# How to detect locked screen / login-session from a script?

Tags: macos, script, screen-lock

I am looking a way for a script (either bash or AppleScript, doesn't matter) to detect whether the state of the screen or the user login session is locked or not (i.e. the user will need to type in its credential to get back to her/his session).

This is different than detecting whether screen saver is on, which is already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390123/, as active screen saver is not always the same as locked session.

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: How do you propose the script handle multiple users being logged in simultaneously?

Comment: Script just to check whether the user running it have the screen or not.